# Partial Text match - Uima Ruta

Tags: uima, ruta

Whether a partial text match is possible in Ruta (WORDTABLE)?

**Sample Input:**
    yearbook
    book
    databook
    worship
    friendship 
    yearbook

**Sample CSV:**
   book;b.
   ship;sh.

I have a sample CSV file and a sample input where I need to match a word which ends with "book" and "ship".Needs to assign feature value from column 2.

Comment: You can use the normal dictionary lookup of WORDTABLE and WORDLIST, if the text is processed by a decompounder/word splitter. The dictionary lookup works on RutaBasic, which are automatically created. Is that an option?

Comment: @PeterKluegl I've tried WORDTABLE but finds only the word **book**

Comment: What I meant is that you could add a decompounder that created separate annotations for year and book. Then, the WORDLIST/WORDTABLE should also find book in yearbook.

Comment: How do I decompound because CSV file will contain multiple entries?

Comment: I would do it with another analysis engine like a wrapper jwordsplitter or something

Comment: @PeterKluegl Yeah, I agree. But Is this the only way to do?

Comment: There are many ways. If you want to use the WORDLIST/WORDTABLE functionality in Ruta, then you need to create smaller annotations somehow. A simple regex rule would also be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could make use of regular expressions:

```
DECLARE MyWord(String ending);
W{REGEXP(".*book\b") -> CREATE(MyWord, "ending"="b");
```

Or you could use string functions:

```
w:W{endsWith(w.ct, "book") -> CREATE(MyWord, "ending"="b")};
```